# Why isn't Internet Explorer respecting any stylesheets?

Tags: windows, internet-explorer, colors, styles, appearance

This question is not about my own computer, but a shared computer that I sometimes manage. It seems one of the users changed some setting so now every webpage you visit looks just plain wrong. I've included a screenshot here of the Google homepage, but it's doing this kind of thing with any and every website I visit.

[image: Not loading stylesheets properly]

As you can see, everything looks really "boxy"; it's got borders where it shouldn't, and so on. Does anyone know what this user might have done to have caused this change in IE? And what I need to do in order to change things back? Thanks very much!

Comment: Can you list any add-ons that are installed in the browser?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I could find nothing that allowed me to reproduce this behavior, nor have I ever seen that happen before. I would try opening IE with no add-ons (usually in Start>Accessories>System Tools), and if that does not work, I would consider going to Tools>Internet Options>Advanced>Reset and doing that.

I am not even sure that it is just a browser setting, but the latter option will probably tell you for sure.

Comment: Doing the Reset fixed it. First I tried opening it in "No Addons' mode, but that didn't solve anything. But then I tried your suggestion of resetting it to the default settings, and that did the trick. Thanks!

Comment: @SoaperGEM I am glad that worked. That can fix a lot of things, but I have no idea how it started in the first place. At least you are better now. Thank you very much for marking the answer. I greatly appreciate it.