# After Update, Internet Explorer has Terrible Formatting, what caused this?

Tags: windows-xp, internet-explorer, formatting, internet-explorer-8, automatic-update

After an automatic security update for Windows XP, Internet Explorer 8 has stopped rendering pages properly.

Tables cut off text and images overlap other page content.
All drop-down boxes look like they've been cut in half horizontally and only show the top half of their text.
All website buttons are half of their normal size, including their text, but otherwise look fine.

I've uninstalled IE8 and this issue continues to happen on IE6.
I removed the update, but the issue persists.

I haven't been able to duplicate this problem on any other machine.

What could be causing this and how could I reverse it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would try going to Tools>Internet options>Advanced, and Reset the browser. This fixed a similar issue for another poster recently.

[Why isn't Internet Explorer respecting any stylesheets?](https://superuser.com/questions/307940/why-isnt-internet-explorer-respecting-any-stylesheets)

Comment: This worked.  Thank you.  Like the other person in the question you linked, running it with no addons didn't solve anything.